# How to load other page inside the page in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have 4 pages in the project.

```
[
  { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component },
  { path: 'page4', component: Page4Component },
]
```

In page4, I retrieve a URL from the backend which is one of `/page1`, `/page2`, `/page3`. And then I have to embed that page in `/page4`.

I am currently doing it with `iframe` but it's not good.

Is there any way to do it using `ng-template` or something else?

Comment: you can use component's selector tag and ngswitch combination.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt thank you for your suggestion but the project is much more complex than the code I wrote in the question. It should embed the pages from the other modules that is using lazy-loading and those modules shouldn't be imported. The only option I can use is URL of the page.

Comment: I need to embed `page` not the `component`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
{path : 'profile', component: ProfileComponent , 
            children : [
              {path: '' , component: ProfileBoardComponent },
              {path: 'friends' , component: ProfileFriendsComponent }
            ]},
```

Or you mean this in your html components?

```
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Whit `<app-menu>` bein a component

Comment: Not really, they're individual pages without any relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many `router-outlet`'s as you want so you should try using one inside the page4 that will implies you have to modify your routing.

In that manner, when you go to page2, for example, it is going to appear in that router-outlet of the page4.

I understand that you don't want to import other modules maybe matter of perfomance and loadtimes, but in that case you can avoid that case using a `SharedModule` only sharing those components in that manner we avoid that module "x" doesn't know about the module "y".

I think is just matter of architecture but only you understand the project complexity.

Good luck developer!